# lost focus ContentEditable DIV?

Tags: javascript

And I have an editable div :

```
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true"> Enter your text here.. </div>
```

I want when I choose some element in a Dropdown component to change the font for selected text in the editable div, but every time I click on an item in that Dropdown component, I loose focus on the editable div.

I already searched about this problem but I couldn't find anything understandable.

In this post : [dont-lose-focus-when-clicking-another-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215211/dont-lose-focus-when-clicking-another-element), I found this code :

```
protect: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return setTimeout(300)
    }
```

But I don't know how to add it into my code.

please if someone could help me with this problem I'll be gratful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you just need to

1. halt the event from mousedown with that little protection function you have
2. but still handle your clicking event.

   ```
   heres the example, focus on the input first than you click hi

   var protect = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       return setTimeout(300)
   }

   var handleClick = function(){
       alert('hi')
   }

    $('div')
       .on('mousedown', protect)
       .on('click', handleClick) 
    })
   ```

This is how you do it assume you are using jquery  http://jsfiddle.net/yF6Gg/

Comment: What's $('div') ? and what's that handleClick ?

Comment: did you look at the demo on jsfiddle?, that div just anything that you want to click on, eg your menu or your menus buttons. and handle click just a function that you can assign what you want to do when you click.